# How to move cropbox window in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a plugin called [Cropbox](https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox) to crop images. This plugin gives the user a preview of how the image will be cropped and they can crop it as they please. I'd like to know how I can change the position of the cropping window without changing the position of the div it's in. For example, I'd like to give one of the cropping windows a margin-left of 10px. I don't want both windows to be given a margin-left change, only one window. How do I accomplish this? Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1hno508/).

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div id='imgContainer'>
    <div id='elements'>
      <input type='file' id='choice1'>
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type='file' id='choice2'>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $("#choice1").on('change', function() {
    $("#elements").hide();
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {

        });
      });
      $('#imgContainer').append($img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

$(function() {

  $("#choice2").on('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var $img = $('<img />').attr({
        src: reader.result
      });

      $img.on('load', function() {
        $img.cropbox({
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {

        });
      });
      $('#imgContainer').append($img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is this what you need https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/em7dd7z5/1/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Yes, but I have 2 cropbox windows in the same container. How do I control only one of them?

Comment: @user2896120 why don't you have both cropbox windows in your fiddle if that's your actual use case?

Comment: @user2896120 I'm assuming you have a unique container for each window. So you would give each a class or ID or something, then use `.el1 .cropFrame {}, .el2 .cropFrame {}` in your CSS to target them uniquely.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Sorry, I wanted to make the problem simple and easy to understand. I have updated the jsFiddle. Both windows are appended to the same container

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r1hno508/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/r1hno508/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Works great, thanks!

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll submit as an answer if you're going to keep the question open. I looked and didn't find any other posts on it so it might be useful

Comment: @MichaelCoker Sure thing